# Difference between Left and Right

Tags: haskell

In the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" in the [section about functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) there is an example involving `Either` which I don't understand:

```haskell
ghci> fmap (replicate 3) (Right "blah")
Right ["blah","blah","blah"]
```

```haskell
ghci> fmap (replicate 3) (Left "foo")
Left "foo"
```

Why is the latter not `Left ["foo", "foo", "foo"]`?

Comment: If you want the latter behaviour, [Either is a bifunctor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-4.2/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Left` constructor on `Either` is implemented as the "failure case". Like other functors, once this failure value enters the equation, it prevents any real computations from happening. So, when you apply `fmap` to `Left "foo"` it immediately returns the same "failure" value.

You can see this by looking at how `Either` implements `fmap`:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
    fmap f (Left x) = Left x
```

The idea here is that `Left "foo"` would actually be something more descriptive, like `Left "Value could not be computed"`. If you try to apply further functions to that value, you just want the "error" to get passed along intact.

If it helps, just imagine how `fmap` would work on some other type where the failure case is more obvious, e.g.:

```
-- Maybe: failure value is `Nothing`
fmap (replicate 3) (Nothing)
```

This produces `Nothing`, not `[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I had already understood the `Maybe` behaviour. What helped me with `Either` is to remind myself that not `Either` is a functor, but `Either a`!

Comment: @mkrieger1 A simple mnemonic rule to remember which is which: the `Right` case stands for correct/successful/"right", the `Left` one stands for "not right" hence wrong/incorrect/failing.